# Run Spark in standalone mode with Scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-2.11

I follow the instructions to build Spark with Scala 2.11:

```
mvn -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

Then I launch per instructions:

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
```

It fails with two lines in the log file:

```
Failed to find Spark assembly in /etc/spark-1.2.1/assembly/target/scala-2.10
You need to build Spark before running this program.
```

Obviously, it's looking for a scala-2.10 build, but I did a scala-2.11 build. I tried the obvious -Dscala-2.11 flag, but that didn't change anything. The docs don't mention anything about how to run in standalone mode with scala 2.11.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before building you must run the script under:

> dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh

Which should replace references to 2.10 with 2.11.

> Note that this will not necessarily work as intended with non-GNU sed (e.g. OS X)

Comment: I ran this script. It didn't help. I get the exact same error referencing assembly/target/scala-2.10. I tried this in both Spark 1.2.1 (preferable) and the latest Spark 1.3.0 just to check.

Comment: Are you on a linux machine? The other option is just to manually edit the script yourself.

Comment: Yes, Linux. CentOS VM to be specific. I didn't get any errors. Is there any way I can verify that the sed command succeeded?

Comment: The script seems to have worked. This came back blank: grep -r --include=pom.xml "_2.10" .

Comment: You could just run:

`export SPARK_SCALA_VERSION="2.11"`

And then run it again

Comment: that works. I actually just figured that out after grepping for the only remaining reference to 2.10. thanks!

Comment: For Spark `1.6.1` `dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh` script is deprecated and now it is `dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.11`.